# Node.js short syntax or mistake: Class = new(require(‘./class.js’))();

Tags: node.js

why not 1 line 1 var:

```
var Class = new(require(‘./class.js’))();
```

instead common way of 2 lines and 2 vars:

```
var Class = require(‘./class.js’);
var object = new Class();
```

Comment: In a word - readability.

Comment: what about node.js caching? readability in 1 line maybe much better,and where it multi includes even more

Answer (score -1):

I see numerous issues with this approach.

1. If you move the code between files, you have to update the path in every object instantiation.
2. If you move the file, you have to update much more requires.
3. This makes your code less portable - if you will ever use it on client, with different approach for including scripts, you will have to change your code.
4. You just need to type more to instantiate a class.
5. This is not how most (probably 99.9%) of the other people do it.
6. It postpones the "missing module" error to the latter time - this is quite dangerous.
7. This is probably not in line with future ES6 modular approach.
8. Well, maybe too personal, but I just do not like it.
9. Can't stop adding points to this list. Help me! Aaaaa!

Well. Now it is under control. Actually, nice trick. I will use it but not for anything bigger than one line. :)

Comment: no 1 of your reasons is the true reason to prefer 2 lines approach - for my view of point

Comment: Sorry Yosef, I don't care - if the above is not enough, wait for better answer or try to find a truth in another place